# The content changes it's position on second click of the same anchor link on a fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a single-page website with fixed header. The problem I'm facing is that when I click on the nav-bar link, it goes exactly to the content but when I click again on the same link. It slightly changes the position of the content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm26n.jpg

JS: var windows = $(window);
    var sticky = $('#sticker');

```
windows.on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = windows.scrollTop();
    if (scroll < 400) {
        sticky.removeClass('stick');
    }else{
        sticky.addClass('stick');
    }
});



$('a.pagess:not(:first)').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var y = 125;
        $('html ,body').animate({enter code here
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - y
        });

});
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it seems to work fine so try to create a jsFiddle and update your question with a link to it.

Comment: If you want sticky header you now can use pure CSS no need for JS code anymore (use `display: sticky` you can google this, it have some quirks). Maybe it will fix the problem with jumping.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I got it, actually my calculation was a bit wrong. So I changed the code a little bit and it's all right now.

```
 $('a.pagess:not(:first)').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var y = 125;
        if (windows.scrollTop() > 400 ){
            y = 55;
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - y
        });

        window.history.pushState(null, null, this.href);

    });
```